# Googe business review api header authorization expired frequently

Tags: magento2.4.1, google-api, authorize

I am getting reviews from google business, i am using header Authorization Bearer, its frequently expired, again and again i am updating my Bearer token,  how to handle this situation.

May i know the best practice for handling this situation?

Answer (score 0):

#### Token always expires in 24 hours So you need to get token programmatically using below curl code

```
$apiURL = "API URL";
$credentials = array("userName" => "username", "password" => "password");
$json_credentials = json_encode($credentials);
$ch = curl_init($apiURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_credentials);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","Content-Length: ".strlen($json_credentials)));

$token = curl_exec($ch);
$token = json_decode($token);
echo $token->token;
//Close handle
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: $credentials = array("userName" => "username", "password" => "password"); --> my gmail account credientials?